# Passing data from rails to js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following the railscast tutorial on nested forms, but the code seems quite old and I'm interested in using modern techniques.The problem is that I want to generate a link which will as response add new textbox(new nested model instance) via javascript.This is the original code

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
  end
```

I wanted to replace this `link_to_function` and came up with this code

```
link_to name, '#', 'data-assoc' => "#{association}", 'data-fields' => "#{fields}", class: 'add-new'
```

and wrote js onclick handler for `add-new` class, that will simply grab data from `data-` and insert it into html.
However, it seems just ugly having that html inside attributes.Is there a better way to pass that html to js, or maybe different approach to dynamically adding html ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Dynamically add fields in rails with out nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839147/dynamically-add-fields-in-rails-with-out-nested-attributes) The last answer I have a nested association, but rather than use accepts_nested_attributes_for, I handled the association in the controller. I like this because I am handling the logic in Ruby (where I'm more comfortable) rather than JS.