# How to create one string out of many inputs in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to create a form in rails where I have two inputs like dose and name here I am adding dose and name once but I want to use this form to create a string for example I can have dose20+dose30+dose40 as a string can you help me . How can I create this string before saving it to my table should I use javascript or is there any way by which i can use it in rails .

Answer (score 1):

If you need this compound string only for save, not in view. You can do id in controller method like this

```
def update
 string = "#{params[:dose20]}#{params[:dose30]}#{params[:dose40]}"
 ...
end
```

Or use before_save callback inside model.

My be you looking for smt like this https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields  or this [Dynamically add fields in rails with out nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839147/dynamically-add-fields-in-rails-with-out-nested-attributes/17926645) ?

Comment: I have a one input form and submit button I want to add it one by one to create a string and then I want to add it to my table .

Comment: My be you looking for smt like this https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields  or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839147/dynamically-add-fields-in-rails-with-out-nested-attributes/17926645 ?

Comment: I can do it in javascript easily I was trying to find a way to do it in rails way thanks for reply .