# Dynamically add a text field whenever clicking on add button in Rails application

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic-forms

I'm developing a food recipe app where a user can post their cooking recipe.
I'm stuck on the part where the user describes the steps for preparation.  I want to add a text field for each step. Is there any way to do so?
I am using **Rails 7.0.5**

I want to have more 'step' fields dynamically.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: @recipe, local: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :recipe_name %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :step %>
<% end %>
```

Any methods using javascript or some other gem would be acceptable.

Comment: The `cocoon` gem has always been my go to for this. While it is a bit older at this point there are tutorials still implementing this in rails 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add fields in rails with out nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839147/dynamically-add-fields-in-rails-with-out-nested-attributes)